# Next.JS implement external ".js" with <script>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, react-dom

Im Building a website with Next.Js and I tried to implement an external .js file (Bootstrap.min.js & Popper.min.js) but it is not displayed.
Im not sure what the problem is!

I implemented it like this:

```html
import Head from 'next/head';

//partials
import Nav from './nav'

const Layout = (props) => (
<div>
    <Head>
        <title>Site</title>

        {/* Meta tags */}
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"></meta>
        
        {/* Standard page css */}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/page.css"/>
        
        {/* Bootstrap CSS */}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/includes/bootstrap.min.css"/>

        {/* jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS */}
        <script src="/static/includes/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/includes/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
    </Head>
    <Nav/>
    {props.children}
</div>
);

export default Layout;
```

It looks good to me? what am I missing, it's not projecting as it should!

When I tried a script inside the page it shows "Hello JavaScript" for a very short time and then it disappears?

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript";</script>
```

How do i fix it?

Please help!

Im Using:
    "next": "^8.0.3",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4"

Comment: Hello, please how did you solve this ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `Script` tag from `next/script` for importing external `.js` files.

The following is an example snippet from one of my projects. I had to import the script at the end of the page due to some DOM manipulations so the `Script` tag worked exceptionally well :)

```
import Script from "next/script";
import Content from "../components/Content";
import Header from "../components/Header";

const index = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Content />
      <Script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/main.js" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default index;
```

Comment: Only available with Next.js >= 11

Comment: Not working with dangerouslySetInnerHTML. I am applying string in it but didn't work

Answer (score 19):

1. You need to put all your scripts inside the `Head` tag.
2. Don't put raw javascript inside the `Head` tag. Put it in a separate file and import the script in the `Head` tag

You can create a `.js` file, which contains your raw js code, in the `public` folder and then use the script in the `Head` tag. I am not sure why we have to do this, but this is how it works in Next.js

So for your problem, this will work:

`public/js/myscript.js`

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript";
```

`Layout.js`

```
import Head from 'next/head';

const Layout = (props) => (
<div>
    <Head>
        {/* import external javascript */}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myscript.js"></script>
    </Head>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
);

export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 5):

This is working as Expected for me.

```
<script
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
  __html: `
  console.log('Console message');
`,
}}
/>
```

Comment: This approach is recommended by a Next.js engineer here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8891#issuecomment-536192888

`Hi, it looks like you need to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML here since React escapes the characters by default`

Answer (score 2):

@GunnerFan was in the right path. NextJS recommends putting these files in the `public` folder

So

```
import Head from "next/head";

// ... elsewhere in your code 
<HEAD>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></script>
</HEAD>
```

You can refer to files in the folder directly, e.g: `js/<your file>`
Be careful not to name them same as files in the pages directory, i.e 
INCORRECT: `pages/myscript.js` & `js/myscript.js`

Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving