# How to import a vendor script into nextjs

Tags: next.js

My app requires a script that isn't on npm so I have the file in my project folder, but how can I use it in my nextJs app?

I have tried putting the script in the `public` folder and then using `next/head`:

```
<Head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/CustomEase.min.js"></script>
</Head>
```

but the script cannot be found.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `src="/CustomEase.min.js"`. The `public` folder is the root folder for your public URL.

Comment: Where is the correct place to put <script src="/CustomEase.min.js"></script>` to have the script loaded globally?

Comment: You can either put it in the `Head` tag of a [wrapper component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165852/next-js-implement-external-js-with-script) (like a Layout component), or in a custom `_document.js` file: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document

Comment: didnt work when i put script inside head. worked when i put it in body

Answer (score 1):

hmmm, that's how I am loading vendor scripts, i.e. jQuery. If its asset resource file you're hosting then move that file(s) into the `Public` folder and then you should be able to access it with a relative path:

note: it's important to put the "/" as Next will start pretending pages name to your path name...particularly when you do Dynamic Routing i.e. `pages -> randompage -> [param].js` could result in `/randompage/js/somefile.js` to your resource path if you exclude the `/`

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"></link>
        <title>Title Here</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/somefile.css" />
        <script src="/js/somefile.js"></script>
      </Head>
      {children}
      <script src="/js/somefile.js"></script>
    )
}
export default Layout
```

Comment: Where is the correct place to put <script src="/CustomEase.min.js"></script>` to have the script loaded globally?

Comment: @MarkSteggles You can put it anywhere on your root level component, just make sure the actual assets are in your `Public` folder. Static files and assets should be in Public so your project builds properly [Next.js Static Files](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving). I think you had it right, just leave `/public/*` out of the resource path as Next is smart enough to know static files are in `Public` folder. Try: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/CustomEase.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to import third party JS files into Next.js project.

Here are ways recommended by Next.js team.

1. Adding Third-Party JavaScript

Scripts that need to load and execute as soon as possible are usually added within the  of a page. Using a regular HTML  element, an external script would be added as follows:

```
<Head>
  <title>First Post</title>
  <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js" />
</Head>
```

2. Using the Script Component

next/script is an extension of the HTML  element and optimizes when additional scripts are fetched and executed.

In the same file, add an import for Script from next/script at the beginning of the file:

```
import Script from 'next/script';
```

Now, update the `FirstPost` component to include the `Script` component:

```
export default function FirstPost() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>First Post</title>
      </Head>
      <Script
        src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"
        strategy="lazyOnload"
        onLoad={() =>
          console.log(`script loaded correctly, window.FB has been populated`)
        }
      />
      <h1>First Post</h1>
      <h2>
        <Link href="/">← Back to home</Link>
      </h2>
    </>
  );
}
```