# How to import external JS file in Next.js 12

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I need to import a local JS file in my Next.js project. While using:

```js
<Script type="text/javascript" src="/js.js"></Script>
```

I get the error:

[image: 404 Not Found]

When using the `script` tag.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js.js"></script>
```

I get the error "Synchronous scripts should not be used."

---

Looking at the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) and a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61848703/17408627), they say to put static files in the public directory. Doing that gives the same errors as shown above. Am I doing something wrong while importing or is there some other way to import these in Next.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple fix is to use the `<Script>` tag provided by Next.JS in the following manor:

```
<Script id="something to identify this">
{`Put your JS between these backticks`}
</Script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use async or defer.
next js documentation - https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-sync-scripts

```
<script src="/js.js" async />
<script src="/js.js" defer />
```